# How to change styles of a DOM element

Tags: javascript

There is an easy html like this:

```
<div id="btc"></div>
```

And some .js code as follows:

```
setInterval(function () {
    var HttpClient = function () {
        this.get = function (aUrl, aCallback) {
            var anHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            anHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (anHttpRequest.readyState == 4 && anHttpRequest.status == 200)
                    aCallback(anHttpRequest.responseText);
            }

            anHttpRequest.open("GET", aUrl, true);
            anHttpRequest.send(null);
        }
    }
    var price = 1;
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.get('https://blockchain.info/ru/ticker', function (response) {
        var fields = ['last'];
        var data = JSON.parse(response);
        var out = [];
        for (var i in data) {
            var d = [];
            for (var j in fields)
                d.push(data[i][fields[j]]);
            out.push(d);
        }
        console.log(out[0]);
        if (out[0] > price) {
            console.log('more');
            document.getElementById('btc').innerHTML = out[0];
            document.getElementById('btc').style.color = "green";
        }
        price = out[0];
        if (out[0] < price) {
            console.log('less');
            price = out[0];
            document.getElementById('btc').innerHTML = out[0];
            document.getElementById('btc').style.color = "red";
        }

    });
}, 1000)
```

The idea is to mark the price with red or green in case it falls or rises.
Till now it only works with rising (second if never works).
What am I doing wrong and how can I correct it? ;)

Comment: why didnt you use else ?

Comment: @NoushadPP cause I need to somehow redeclare price variable and I don't know how ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove line `price = out[0];` and move `var price = 1` before `setInterval` function.

Below is correct code:

```
    var price = 1;
    setInterval(function () {
        var HttpClient = function () {
            this.get = function (aUrl, aCallback) {
                var anHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
                anHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (anHttpRequest.readyState == 4 && anHttpRequest.status == 200)
                        aCallback(anHttpRequest.responseText);
                }

                anHttpRequest.open("GET", aUrl, true);
                anHttpRequest.send(null);
            }
        }

        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.get('https://blockchain.info/ru/ticker', function (response) {
            var fields = ['last'];
            var data = JSON.parse(response);
            var out = [];
            for (var i in data) {
                var d = [];
                for (var j in fields)
                    d.push(data[i][fields[j]]);
                out.push(d);
            }
            console.log(price)
            if (out[0] > price) {
                console.log('more');
                price = out[0];
                document.getElementById('btc').innerHTML = out[0];
                document.getElementById('btc').style.color = "green";
            }
            else if (out[0] < price) {
                console.log('less');
                price = out[0];
                document.getElementById('btc').innerHTML = out[0];
                document.getElementById('btc').style.color = "red";
            }
        });
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: the problem is as I guess also in var price = 1
Means that I need to reassign some value to it while on-going already...

Comment: If you have `price = out[0];` before `if (out[0] < price)` this if always be false.

Comment: that's fine. Do i need to declare price as 1 at the very begining?

Comment: I fix your code by moving `var price=1` before `setInterval` function, I check it and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the code

```
price = out[0];
if (out[0] < price) {
```

see this block of code. You are setting the value of `out[0]` in `price` and comparing `if (out[0] < price)` which is always `false`. That is why your second if is not working.

So, you need to remove the code `price = out[0]`. And you can even use `if-else` instead of two `if` block

```
if (out[0] > price) {
      console.log('more');
      document.getElementById('btc').innerHTML = out[0];
      document.getElementById('btc').style.color = "green";
}
else {
     console.log('less');
     price = out[0];
     document.getElementById('btc').innerHTML = out[0];
     document.getElementById('btc').style.color = "red";
}
```

Comment: as I wrote above the problem is hidden in declaration of price. This code still does not work..